# Get comments for more than one post

Tags: comments

I would like to get all the comments for a group of post (not only one post.

I tried

```
$comment_args = array('number' => '14', 'post_id' => '10,20,30,40'  );
    $comments = get_comments($comment_args);
    foreach($comments as $comment) ...
```

But does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `'post_id'` is converted to a positive integer in `WP_Comment_Query`, so you cannot successful pass anything else to `get_comments()`.

You have to filter `'comments_clauses'`. Here you can change the `WHERE` clause to use `comment_post_ID IN ( $ids )` instead of `comment_post_ID = $id`.

I would use a static class as a wrapper for `get_comments()`.

### Sample code

```
/**
 * Query comments for multiple post IDs.
 */
class T5_Multipost_Comments
{
    /**
     * Post IDs, eg. array ( 1, 2, 40 )
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $post_ids = array ();

    /**
     * Called like get_comments.
     *
     * @param  array $args
     * @param  array $post_ids
     * @return array
     */
    public static function get( $args = array (), $post_ids = array () )
    {
        if ( array () !== $post_ids )
        {
            self::$post_ids = $post_ids;
            add_filter( 'comments_clauses', array ( __CLASS__, 'filter_where_clause' ) );
        }
        return get_comments( $args );
    }

    /**
     * Filter the comment query
     *
     * @param array $q Query parts, see WP_Comment_Query::query()
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function filter_where_clause( $q )
    {
        $ids       = implode( ', ', self::$post_ids );
        $_where_in = " AND comment_post_ID IN ( $ids )";

        if ( FALSE !== strpos( $q['where'], ' AND comment_post_ID =' ) )
        {
            $q['where'] = preg_replace(
                '~ AND comment_post_ID = \d+~',
                $_where_in,
                $q['where']
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $q['where'] .= $_where_in;
        }

        remove_filter( 'comments_clauses', array ( __CLASS__, 'filter_where_clause' ) );
        return $q;
    }
}
```

### Usage example

```
$multi_comments = T5_Multipost_Comments::get(
    array ( 'number' => '14' ), // comment args
    array ( 149, 564, 151 )     // post IDs
);
print '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars( print_r( $multi_comments, TRUE ) ) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: +1 Still wonder, why you're using `__CLASS__` when calling `remove_filter`, but not `__FUNCTION/METHOD__`.

Comment: @kaiser `__CLASS__` for syntactical requirements by PHP, the function name for readability.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, `get_comments()` doesn't quite work that way.  If you specify a post ID, the function will *only* return comments for that post.  The post ID parameter does not accept multiple IDs.

However, you could write a function to recursively fetch comments from an array of posts and use that instead:

```
get_comments_from_range( $post_ids ) {
    foreach( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
        $comment_collection[] = get_comments( array( 'post_id' => $post_id ) );
    }

    return $comment_collection;
}

$comments = get_comments_from_range( array( '10', '20', '30', '40' ) );
```

Once you have the array inside your function, you can order it however you need and limit it to only 14 or so comments ... it's up to you.