# Get comments only for certain specific users in template file

Tags: comments

To return comments for a specific user, I use the code below:

```
$arg = array('user_id' => $userID); 
$coms= get_comments( $arg );
```

How can I modify the  arguments of this function so that I get comments for a group of users (get only comments for specific 2 or 3 users)?

The arguemnt 'user_id' should be an integer, I cant find a way to pass an array.

Or should I use PHP or SQL to get my goal?

Your time and consideration of this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55164/get-comments-for-more-than-one-post

Comment: No, that won't work...read the answers! :) ok, you realized that yourself :D The answers are for `post_id`'s but it shouldn't be that hard to make it work for `user_id`'s.

Comment: I totally agree with you. by analogy to post_id, I should resolve the issue which  is not simple as I thought at the beginning. Thank you very much for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to modify the query using the `comments_clauses` filter:

```
$args = array( 'user_id' => 0 );
add_filter( 'comments_clauses', 'custom_comments_clauses');
$comments = get_comments( $args );
remove_filter( 'comments_clauses', 'custom_comments_clauses');

function custom_comments_clauses( $clauses ){
    $clauses['where'] = str_replace( 'user_id = 0', 'user_id IN (1, 2, 3)', $clauses['where'] );
    return $clauses;
}
```

### Update:

You could also add a custom parameter, `my_user_ids`, to the query like this:

```
$args = array( 'user_id' => 0, 'my_user_ids' => array(1,2,3) );

add_filter( 'comments_clauses', 'custom_comments_clauses', 99, 2 );
$comments = get_comments( $args );
remove_filter( 'comments_clauses', 'custom_comments_clauses', 99, 2 );

function custom_comments_clauses( $clauses, $query ){
    if( isset( $query->query_vars['user_id'] ) && isset( $query->query_vars['my_user_ids'] ) ){ 
        $user_id = $query->query_vars['user_id'];
        $user_ids = $query->query_vars['my_user_ids'];
        if( count( $user_ids ) > 0 ){
            $from = sprintf( 'user_id = %d', $user_id );
            $to   = sprintf( 'user_id IN (%s)', join( ',', $user_ids ) );
            $clauses['where'] = str_replace( $from, $to, $clauses['where'] );
        }
    }
    return $clauses;
}
```

where `$my_user_ids` is an array of user ID's.

Comment: This is a logical approach. I will  implement it and come back accept.+1

Comment: Honnestly I dont have enough knowledge to understand this, so I posted another thread which describes my detailed goal with a simple approach. Thank you very much. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105029/comments-template-not-working-correcly-in-custom-template-files