# comments_template not working correcly in custom template files

Tags: comments, templates, comments-template

In a template file that I am using as page, I want to allow only 2 users to post comments and allow to all other users to only see these comments( not allow them add comments).

my template file is:

```
<?php get_header();  ?>

<?php 
if (get_current_user_id()==1 or get_current_user_id()==2 ) {

comments_template( '', true );
                    }
else
{
comments_template( '/comments-with-no-form.php', true );

} ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Normally, when I remove `comments_template` from single.php, or just remove the `<?php comment_form(); ?>` from comments.php, changes apply. But in separate template file, nothing is working. The file `comments-with-no-form.php` is never executed (only style of comments.php changes).

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This if statement is really wrong :

```
if (get_current_user_id()==1 or get_current_user_id()==2
```

should be :

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if ($user_id==1 || $user_id==2 )
```

Comment: waw. I was thinking the problem is in comments_template. what is wrong in my statement? is is the `or`.

Comment: Ahhhh, In my editor I saw its color changing, my god I thought my editor know only PHP. :-) thanks man

Comment: [`or` is a valid logical operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: I was wrong this is not due to `or` but the way you called `get_current_user_id()` and use it. Sorry :/